# ruby attr_accessor missing method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, getter-setter, attr-accessor, carmen

New to RoR, I'm using the Carmen gem, running a rake gives me the error:

Failed: NoMethodError: undefined method `excluded_states=' for Carmen:Module

but the gem includes the attr_accessor method with :excluded_states in the args.

Doesn't the attr_accessor method automagically create the `excluded_states=' setter method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `attr_accessor` within a module, that's something that should only work within a class. What you want instead is the [`mattr_accessor`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-module) variant:

```
module MyModule
  mattr_accessor :excluded_states
end
```

It's also possible it is defined correctly but you're referencing it incorrectly, as in you should be calling that on an instance of something.